# make URL case insensitive in Yii2

Tags: php, url, yii, yii2

I'm trying to make the url in Yii 2 accept case insensitive URLs like

```
api/gethotels
api/getHotels
```

How I can make these 2 urls point to the same method ?
If I try to put

```
 'caseSensitive'=>false,
```

in urlManager in web.php, it returns

> Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlManager::caseSensitive

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3885

Comment: Stop trying to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix English issues and to make it better.  I marked down the error message with > instead of 4 spaces.

Comment: Do you need all requests to be case insensitive or just a few?

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis Could you please answer this question with your valid reference? it would be helpful for future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The creator of Yii framework (Qiang Xue), says about this feature in Yii2:

> This is dropped because URLs are case sensitive. Case insensitive URLs
>   are not SEO friendly.

You can find the source here:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3885